# How do I calculate expected value and variance, then simulate 500 samples from this distribution in R

Tags: r

Assume we have a discrete random variable with probability function given by

```
x = c(0, 3, 5, 10)
```

and

```
px = c(0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6)
```

How do I calculate expected value and variance, then simulate 500 samples from this distribution in R?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You may want to read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) about the best practices when asking questions about homework. Regarding your question about how to sample from a discrete distribution such as that given in your question, the function name you're looking for is `sample()` (see `help("sample")`). Regarding calculating expected value and variance, I'd answer your question with another question: What are the formulas for expected value and variance? (comment 1/2)

Comment: Even if there weren't canned R functions for them, you could get there if you find the formulas in your book or online. (end)

Comment: I had tried using the mean and var function but they were given different vales as to when i calculated analytically. Hence the posting of the question.

Answer (score 5):

Let

```
x <- c(0, 3, 5, 10)
px <- c(0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6)
```

You can calculate the expectation and variance of x as follows:

```
Ex <- sum(x * px)
Vx <- sum(((x - Ex) ^ 2) * px)
```

Then use `sample` to simulate data:

```
sample(x, size = 500, prob = px, replace = TRUE)
```